# Matrices and images

Tags: calculus, matrices, matrix-calculus, education, random-matrices

Let T: $\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^5$ defined by

$T (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = (x_4, x_1, x_3, x_2, x_1 - x_3)$

A) Find the standard matrix for the linear transformation $T$

B) Find the image of $x = (1, 2, 1, 2)$ by $T$

Can anyone help me out with this question. I have been through my notes but can not understand how to do it. Hopefully, a detailed solution would be the best so I can get a better understanding.

Comment: Hello and welcome to MSE.
Do you know how to build a matrix given a basis of your vector space ?

Comment: The standard matrix of $T$ is the $5 \times 4$ matrix with columns $T(1,0,0,0)$, $T(0,1,0,0)$, $T(0,0,1,0)$, and $T(0,0,0,1)$. To explain why this is the case may involve delving into your chosen definition of matrix multiplication or what the "standard matrix" is defined to be, but that's what it is. The second part is simply asking for $T(1,2,1,2)$, and can be computed without necessarily identifying the matrix because you have a formula for $T$. It will turn out to be equal to the matrix product of the standard matrix of $T$ with $(1,2,1,2)$ written as a $4 \times 1$ column vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is important to see how matrices act on vectors. In our case, we are transforming vectors from $\mathbb{R}^4$ into vectors in $\mathbb{R}^5$ (i.e. T will transform a vector $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ into $b =(b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4,b_5)$. If we write a general transformation T:
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
t_{11} & t_{12} & t_{13} & t_{14}\\
t_{21} & t_{22} & t_{23} & t_{24}\\
t_{31} & t_{32} & t_{33} & t_{34}\\
t_{41} & t_{42} & t_{43} & t_{44}\\
t_{51} & t_{52} & t_{53} & t_{54}\\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3} \\
x_{4} \\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1} \\
b_{2} \\
b_{3} \\
b_{4} \\
b_{5} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

where

\begin{cases} 
 b_1 =  t_{11} x_1 + t_{12} x_2 + t_{13} x_3 +  t_{14} x_4\\
 b_2 =  t_{21} x_1 + t_{22} x_2 + t_{23} x_3 +  t_{24} x_4\\
 b_3 =  t_{31} x_1 + t_{32} x_2 + t_{33} x_3 +  t_{34} x_4\\
 b_4 =  t_{41} x_1 + t_{42} x_2 + t_{43} x_3 +  t_{44} x_4\\
 b_5 =  t_{51} x_1 + t_{52} x_2 + t_{53} x_3 +  t_{54} x_4
\end{cases}

Back to our exercise:

\begin{cases} 
 b_1 & = x_4&=  0 \cdot x_1 &+ 0 \cdot x_2 &+ 0 \cdot x_3 &+  1 \cdot x_4 \\
 b_2 &=x_1&=  1 \cdot x_1 &+ 0\cdot x_2 &+ 0 \cdot x_3 &+  0 \cdot x_4  \\
 b_3 & = x_3&=  0 \cdot x_1 &+ 0 \cdot x_2 &+1 \cdot x_3 &+  0 \cdot x_4\\
 b_4 & = x_2&=  0 \cdot x_1 &+ 1 \cdot x_2 &+0 \cdot x_3 &+  0 \cdot x_4\\
 b_5 & = x_1-x_3&=  1 \cdot x_1 &+ 0 \cdot &+ (-1) \cdot x_3 &+  0 \cdot x_4
\end{cases}

Then,

\begin{equation}
T=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}

For the image of $x = (1,2,1,2)$ just compute:

\begin{equation}
T (1,2,1,2) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
1 \\
2 \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
1 \\
1 \\
2 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Comment: how did you do the image of the vector. What is "just compute" and thanks for answering the question.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I just operate the matrix T with the vector x. I hope the following video help you out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7CBkZq3eQ_0

Answer (score 0):

Each component of the right hand side is a dot product of $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ with the first row of the matrix.  So the first row $a$ is the solution to $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) \cdot (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = x_4$.